# how to change width and height of Youtube player inside of iframe

Tags: css, reactjs, video, iframe

am trying to set height and width of video player inside of a Youtube iframe to be 100% and 100%(full iframe width), but I cant. my Iframe is 100vw anyway but video player inside of it is auto (for quality reasons, I guess), but I want it to be 100vw and I cant change it,

I tried using css selector like this:

```
.content iframe video{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```

but it is not working, I guess it can not see what is inside of iframe? help would be appreciated

Comment: Youtube keeps the video's picture width/height ratio. You cannot stretch it. Why do you need an external Youtube video to be **100w**? For example if it is for a moving background then maybe just download the video and host it on your own server? **(2)** Does increasing viewport **height** (instead of width) help to fill the screen (but width of picture will be cropped obviously)?...

Comment: yeah it was for a landing background, nothing helped so I just downloaded it and uploaded it on the server. :) thanks

Answer (score 1):

To change the width of a video inside an iframe, you can use the following CSS:

```css
.my-video {
  width: your desired width;
}
```

```html
<iframe class="my-video" src="video.mp4"></iframe>
```

If the video tag is inside an iframe that is nested within another element, you can target the video tag specifically by using CSS to select the nested iframe and then the video tag within it.

For example, if the structure of your HTML looks like this:

```css
.container iframe video {
  width: your desired width;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <iframe>
       <video>...</video>
   </iframe>
</div>
```

Alternatively, you can use classes or ids to select the nested iframe and video.

```css
.my-iframe .my-video {
  width: your desired width;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <iframe class="my-iframe">
       <video class="my-video">...</video>
   </iframe>
</div>
```

**Note** that it's also possible to use JavaScript to change the width of the video.

```js
var iframe = document.getElementsByClassName("my-iframe")[0];
var video = iframe.getElementsByTagName("video")[0];
video.style.width = "your desired width";
```

Comment: I tried to use classes or ids to select the nested iframe and video, but when am checking it using inspect element, video is not being targeted by selectors

Comment: You have to check if the iframe contents are loaded or not at that moment. You can do it by adding `onload` event on your iframe `onload="onLoadHandler();"`

Comment: I tried targeting video using css, I cant use js selectors because am using react.js, if you can write me a script for a react.js too, I would appreaciate it very much